# How to write a file line by line in R

Tags: r, csv

I am trying to read a csv file line by line and only select the 2nd and the 3rd cell from left, and the 3rd cell from the right. For example, if there are 17 cells in this line, I am going to take the 15th cell. Then I want to combine those 3 cells, separated by comma, and then to write this line to a new csv file.

Foe now, I am just using a for loop to access each line and then split them by comma. Then I select the cells I want and combine them as a string and append to a big String variable. Once the for-loop finishes, I write out the file by writeLines(). However, it takes a long time to finish this process because there are 2.8 million rows and it takes a lot of memory. Is there any way to make it more efficient? or can I write the output file line by line in the for-loop?

```
FileLinebyLine <- read_lines("testfile.csv")

pt<-proc.time()
NewFile <- ""
RowList <- list()
for (i in 1:length(FileLinebyLine))
{
    a <- strsplit(FileLinebyLine[i],",")
    RowList[i] = paste(a[[1]][2],a[[1]][3],a[[1]][(length(a[[1]]) - 2)], sep = ",")

}
NewFile <- paste(unlist(RowList), sep = "\n")
proc.time()-pt
outputfile <- file("output.txt")
writeLines(NewFile,outputfile)
close(outputfile)
```

I have also tried to use write_lines() in the for loop but it always gives me the error Error in

isOpen(path) : invalid connection

Can anyone help me? Appreciate that!!!

Comment: R is not a good tool for this method. I'd encourage you to use command line tools instead like `sed` or `awk` if your data won't fit in memory. If your data will fit in memory, then it will be much faster in R to read the entire data frame at once (or in, say, 500k row batches), select the columns you want, and then write the output all at once

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can read and write line by line, although I don't know how fast it will be.  Here's an example that read a file line by line, the 4th item in every line and writes to a new file one line at a time:

```
con = file("temp.csv", "r")
while(length(x <- readLines(con, n = 1)) > 0) {
    write(strsplit(x,",")[[1]][4], file="out.csv", append=T)
}
close(con)
```

temp.csv

```
a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h
x,y,z,a,b,c,d,e
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
q,w,e,r,t,y,u,i
```

out.csv

```
d
a
4
r
```

Hope that helps.

Edit: You can also add `library(compiler); enableJIT(3)` to speed up your loops a little.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Thanks! please select and mark as answer if it helps!